# MySQL, переделать запрос для выборки

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть массив, вида

```
[
    {date: '2015-05-01', number: 1},
    {date: '2015-05-01', number: 2},
    {date: '2015-05-03', number: 1},
]
```

Как можно составить запрос для MySQL, что бы вернуть данные по совпадению date AND number в этом массиве.

То есть для таких данных будет запрос:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE
  (date='2015-05-01' AND number=1) OR
  (date='2015-05-01' AND number=2) OR
  (date='2015-05-03' AND number=1)
```

Но, может есть более простой/компактный/красивей вариант?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы можете использовать конструкцию `in` вот так:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE
  (date, number) in (('2015-05-01', 1), ('2015-05-01', 2), ('2015-05-03', 1))
```

[Sql Fiddle пример](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/25455)

Comment: Крутой прием. Забрал в копилку.

Comment: @DenisKhvorostin спасибо! На сколько я знаю - это работает во всех популярных БД, так что точно пригодится.

Comment: кто-нибудь, нажмите еще стрелочку. Этот ответ лучше моего. Автор, это достойно галочки.

Answer (score 3):

Ну только если объединить схожие значения...

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE
  (date='2015-05-01' AND number IN (1, 2)) OR
  (date='2015-05-03' AND number=1)
```

По номеру объединять не стоит... Даты перечислять - больше работы для БД

Comment: Вариант, но это даже немного усложняет.... Может есть в MySQL, что-то типа: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE date IN ('2015-10-12', '2015-10-12') AND number IN (2, 3)` - это конечно не сработает, но суть ясна